# BME680 sensor faulty gas reference readings

Tags: arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

I have a problem with my BME680 readings. I found example code to collect all the air data and make an air quality score (AIQ) out of that (it goes from 0 to 500). You see in the code bellow that in loop() data is collected and AIQ calculated every 2 seconds, and gas reference is updated/collected on every 5-th reading -> `if (getgasreference_count++) % 5 == 0) GetGasReference();` so 5*2 sec= every 10 sec (around 230k ohms).

Problem starts here, where I implement this code in my other program which runs website and controls motors. Here data is collected and AIQ calculated once a minute, gas reference is updated/collected on every 5-th reading -> `if (getgasreference_count++) % 5 == 0) GetGasReference();` so 5*60 sec= every 300 sec= 5 min. Thats when I'm getting faulty gas reference readings (around 100k ohms) and of course following calculated AIQ is wrong.

I'm wondering where the problem is because why it matters when you get new gas reference? I'm thinking that `bme.setGasHeater();` function has something to do with it, but I don't know how it is related with gas reference readings? I would be grateful if anybody can explain where the problem is.

The working example code is here:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BME680.h>

#define SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA (1013.25)

#define YOUR_SENSOR_I2C_ADDRESS 0x76

Adafruit_BME680 bme; // I2C

float hum_weighting = 0.25; // so hum effect is 25% of the total air quality score
float gas_weighting = 0.75; // so gas effect is 75% of the total air quality score

int   humidity_score, gas_score;
float gas_reference = 2500;
float hum_reference = 40;
int   getgasreference_count = 0;
int   gas_lower_limit = 10000;  // Bad air quality limit
int   gas_upper_limit = 300000; // Good air quality limit

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(F("BME680 test"));
  Wire.begin();
  if (!bme.begin(YOUR_SENSOR_I2C_ADDRESS)) {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME680 sensor, check wiring!");
    while (1);
  } else Serial.println("Found a sensor");

  // Set up oversampling and filter initialization
  bme.setTemperatureOversampling(BME680_OS_8X);
  bme.setHumidityOversampling(BME680_OS_2X);
  bme.setPressureOversampling(BME680_OS_4X);
  bme.setIIRFilterSize(BME680_FILTER_SIZE_3);
  bme.setGasHeater(320, 150); // 320°C for 150 ms
  // Now run the sensor to normalise the readings, then use combination of relative humidity and gas resistance to estimate indoor air quality as a percentage.
  // The sensor takes ~30-mins to fully stabilise
  GetGasReference();
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Sensor Readings:");
  Serial.println("  Temperature = " + String(bme.readTemperature(), 2)     + "°C");
  Serial.println("     Pressure = " + String(bme.readPressure() / 100.0F) + " hPa");
  Serial.println("     Humidity = " + String(bme.readHumidity(), 1)        + "%");
  Serial.println("          Gas = " + String(gas_reference)               + " ohms\n");
  Serial.print("Qualitative Air Quality Index ");

  humidity_score = GetHumidityScore();
  gas_score      = GetGasScore();

  //Combine results for the final IAQ index value (0-100% where 100% is good quality air)
  float air_quality_score = humidity_score + gas_score;
  Serial.println(" comprised of " + String(humidity_score) + "% Humidity and " + String(gas_score) + "% Gas");
  if ((getgasreference_count++) % 5 == 0) GetGasReference();
  Serial.println(CalculateIAQ(air_quality_score));
  Serial.println("--------------------------------------------------------------");
  delay(2000);
}

void GetGasReference() {
  // Now run the sensor for a burn-in period, then use combination of relative humidity and gas resistance to estimate indoor air quality as a percentage.
  //Serial.println("Getting a new gas reference value");
  int readings = 10;
  for (int i = 1; i <= readings; i++) { // read gas for 10 x 0.150mS = 1.5secs
    gas_reference += bme.readGas();
  }
  gas_reference = gas_reference / readings;
  //Serial.println("Gas Reference = "+String(gas_reference,3));
}

String CalculateIAQ(int score) {
  String IAQ_text = "air quality is ";
  score = (100 - score) * 5;
  if      (score >= 301)                  IAQ_text += "Hazardous";
  else if (score >= 201 && score <= 300 ) IAQ_text += "Very Unhealthy";
  else if (score >= 176 && score <= 200 ) IAQ_text += "Unhealthy";
  else if (score >= 151 && score <= 175 ) IAQ_text += "Unhealthy for Sensitive Groups";
  else if (score >=  51 && score <= 150 ) IAQ_text += "Moderate";
  else if (score >=  00 && score <=  50 ) IAQ_text += "Good";
  Serial.print("IAQ Score = " + String(score) + ", ");
  return IAQ_text;
}

int GetHumidityScore() {  //Calculate humidity contribution to IAQ index
  float current_humidity = bme.readHumidity();
  if (current_humidity >= 38 && current_humidity <= 42) // Humidity +/-5% around optimum
    humidity_score = 0.25 * 100;
  else
  { // Humidity is sub-optimal
    if (current_humidity < 38)
      humidity_score = 0.25 / hum_reference * current_humidity * 100;
    else
    {
      humidity_score = ((-0.25 / (100 - hum_reference) * current_humidity) + 0.416666) * 100;
    }
  }
  return humidity_score;
}

int GetGasScore() {
  //Calculate gas contribution to IAQ index
  gas_score = (0.75 / (gas_upper_limit - gas_lower_limit) * gas_reference - (gas_lower_limit * (0.75 / (gas_upper_limit - gas_lower_limit)))) * 100.00;
  if (gas_score > 75) gas_score = 75; // Sometimes gas readings can go outside of expected scale maximum
  if (gas_score <  0) gas_score = 0;  // Sometimes gas readings can go outside of expected scale minimum
  return gas_score;
}
```

Comment: For instance, `gas_score` is a global variable, used in `GetGasScore()` and returned to the caller where the value is assigned to the variable `gas_score`... Who wrote this?

Answer (score 0):

From this [Learn Adafruit page](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bme680-humidity-temperature-barometic-pressure-voc-gas/arduino-wiring-test) it seems the gas readouts can take up to **30 minutes** to stabilize.

> Gas is returned as a resistance value in ohms. This value takes up to 30 minutes to stabilize! Once it stabilizes, you can use that as your baseline reading. Higher concentrations of VOC will make the resistance lower.

and on their [first page](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bme680-humidity-temperature-barometic-pressure-voc-gas):

> We recommend that you run this sensor for 48 hours when you first receive it to "burn it in", and then 30 minutes in the desired mode every time the sensor is in use.